# Is it possible to get the eBay Category List via an API programmatically?

Tags: php, drupal-7, ebay-api

My goal is to get a list of eBay categories programmatically.

It appears that the GetCategories method is only available from the Trading API. If I understand correctly, there is user interaction required to log into the Trading API:
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/HowTo/Tokens/GettingTokens.html

Is there another method to get the eBay categories list programmatically?

I'm using Drupal 7, so PHP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need a token to get the categories. All you need is your App-ID

The link below with your APP-ID will return the XML category listing from site: UK (siteid=3)
Setting CategoryID=-1 starts the list at the root level, you can start from any category,
just use IncludeSelector=ChildCategories to get children

http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=YOUR-APP-ID&siteid=3&CategoryID=-1&version=729&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories

Now just use SimpleXML or whatever to parse.

Comment: Currently, it returns only the root level

Comment: Doest it have any JSON feeds or just XML? Thanks

Comment: Great Works  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. how to get subcategories as well?

Comment: See also https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/Concepts/SiteIDToGlobalID.html for a list of siteids.

Answer (score 7):

This may have been correct at the time, however this call in the API now only returns you *one level* of categories, not the entire hierarchy.  To do it for a whole site, in one request (which can get quite large) you need to use the **GetCategories** call with a valid Ebay token, and specify `<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>` and `<ViewAllNodes>true</ViewAllNodes>`.

Also note you will need to update these regularly and provide a mapping algorithm as Ebay expires and remaps categories to new names / ids over time.

Comment: Thanks robbie613. Note that only DetailLevel is required since ViewAllNodes defaults to 'true' - tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following url to get the top level category list. Once you get the list of the categories, you can check if **[LeafCategory]** is true or false. If it is true for the category, you can again fetch the sub-category by specifying the **categoryParentId**. You can use the **php Curl** to get the results and then you can use **simple_xml_object** to fetch the returned xml response


    `$url= 'http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=YOUR-APP-ID&siteid=3&CategoryID=-1&version=729&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories';
    $sXML = download_page($url);
    $oXML = simplexml_load_string($sXML);
    print_r($oXML);exit;
    function download_page($path){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        $retValue = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
        return $retValue;
    }`