# How to get Entire Product Category hierarchy of an ebay site?

Tags: ebay-api

There is an [existing stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114617/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ebay-category-list-via-an-api-programmatically/8150483#8150483) which answers this question but the call isn't working anymore.

I tried adding http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=YOUR-APP-ID&siteid=3&CategoryID=-1&version=729&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories&**DetailLevel=ReturnAll**

But it didn't help.

It is still possible to return the entire hierarchy in one call?

To the call but that didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps this question might help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595106/returning-store-categories-with-ebay-api-using-php

Answer (score 2):

this is what works for me. I am able to get all categories with this URL:

```
var url = "http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping";
        url += "?callname=GetCategoryInfo";
        url += "&appid=YourAppId"; //replace with your appID
        url += "&siteid=0"; //3 = UK | 0 = US
        url += "&callbackname=cb_listCategories"; //callback function
        url += "&CategoryID=-1";
        url += "&version=729";
        url += "&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories";
        url += "&responseencoding=JSON"; //or XML for example
```

After that, it's just a matter of listing the categories on your html by creating a callback function, called "cb_listCategories" in my example.

Please let met know if I can help any further. Take care.